# Recursion is 4 but the expected output is 64

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
  let power2 = (x,n) => {
    if(n == 0) return 1;
    let temp = power2(x,n/2);
    if(n%2 == 1) return temp * temp * x;
    return temp*temp;
}
console.log(power2(4,3));
```

This method has less nodes and time complexity but its giving wrong output

Comment: Consider using a debugger to walk through the execution on line at a time?

Comment: why not just `Math.pow(4, 3)`?

Comment: Just as a mention, you do `let temp = power2(x,n/2);` before your even/odd check, so your next call will be `power2(4, 1.5)`, which will result in awkward behavior, as neither `1.5 == 0` nor `1.5%2 == 1`

Comment: @ASDFGerte That seems like the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the original code was the fact that n / 2 will result in a real number when you need it to be treated as an integer. Bitwise operation are always performed on integers so n >> 1 will correctly yield an integer. The same goes with modulo which converts the number to an integer first that's why it worked correctly in your code.

```
let power2 = (x, n) => {
  if (n === 0) return 1;
  const temp = power2(x, (n >> 1));
  if (n % 2 === 1) return temp * temp * x;
  return temp * temp;
}
console.log(power2(4, 3));
```

Comment: It would improve your answer if you explained why this works, and what the problem with the original code was.

Comment: n /( 2^k) = 1
I have to be more precise and context about this topics,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you need custom integer power function, based on recursion, consider this snippet:

```js
// Custom pow
const myPow = (n, i) => i > 0 ? myPow(n, i - 1) * n : 1;

// Test
console.log(myPow(4, 3));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The original question is using the "exponentiation by squaring" method, which is `O(log(i))` (or `O(i log(n) log(i))` with `BigInt`s) – whereas this approach is using repeated multiplication, which is `O(i)` (or `O(i² log(n))` with `BigInt`s). Plus, it doesn't show where OP went wrong.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Agree, but OP didn't supply any description for his problem, and there is no "exponentiation by squaring" in his task, so he can consider this as an option.

Comment: “This method has less nodes and time complexity” suggests the missing context. But you're right that the original question is vague.